# Does neuroticism go hand in hand with introversion?

Tags: introversion, neuroticism, extraversion

I'm reading [this](http://www.psych.nmsu.edu/~ketelaar/papers_and_abstracts/affectandpersonality.pdf) paper on relations between affect and personality.

It seems the personality domain has been characterized in terms of two dimensions: neuroticism and extraversion.

How does introversion fit into this? There is a clear association between extraversion and measures of positive affect; there is a clear association between neuroticism and measures of negative affect.

Does neuroticism therefore go hand in hand with introversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does neuroticism therefore go hand in hand with introversion?

No, these are different dimensions of personality. One can be therefore be introverted and neurotic, or extroverted and neurotic [1].

With that said, there appears to be a relationship between introversion and neuroticism - a positive correlation of .3 [2]. Rather than one causing the other, it may be because both have a common cause [3].

[1] http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2044-8279.1961.tb02931.x/abstract
[2]http://www.tc.umn.edu/~cdeyoung/Pubs/DeYoung_2007_BFAS_JPSP.pdf
[3]http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19263467